# Changing value of hidden input with jQuery and storing it

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my ASP.NET MVC 3 site there is a table with goods. Each row has hidden input field with bool value.

```
<input name="@string.Format("items[{0}].IsStriked", i)" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

There is handler of button click for each row:

```
$(".shoppingcart a.strike").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $button = $(this);
        var $tr = $button.parents("tr:first");
        if ($("input[name$='IsStriked']", $tr).val() == "false") {
            var $isStriked = $("input[name$='IsStriked']", $tr).val("true");
        }
        else {
            var $isStriked = $("input[name$='IsStriked']", $tr).val("false");
        }
        var $form = $button.parents("form");
        $form.submit();
    });
```

But when I try to change this flag for several rows, I can't. It works only for one row. I suppose that there is because of default value of input. How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: I tried to change value of input by
$("input[name$='IsStriked']", $tr).attr('value', 'false');
but after submit only one row has flag.

Comment: do you have more than one input with the same name?

Comment: it's names are dynamic and creating by counter: string.Format("items[{0}].IsStriked", i)

Comment: Have you checked if the .live("click") fires for each row?

and just a fyi.. live is deprecated in jquery starting 1.7 so you might want to switch to using .on('click' instead

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: also $(".shoppingcart a.strike") if referring to some button click is it not? can you please post the html for that button

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't changed any of your functionality, I have updated the binding to use the latest binding method and simplified the logic within the handler. Give it a try.

```
$('.shoppingcart').on('click', 'a.strike', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $button = $(this),
        $tr = $button.closest('tr'),
        $input = $tr.find('input[name$="IsStriked"]');

    $input.val($input.val() == 'false' ? 'true' : 'false');

    $button.parents("form").submit();
});
```